# U.S. citizen living abroad: How do I declare my income and file for taxes if I've been delinquent in filing?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident, penalty, taxes-owing

I'm 26 and have lived outside the U.S. all my life. I never filed a U.S. income tax return. I know nothing about doing my taxes, and would like to file for the years that I neglected to before the penalties become more serious.  Here are some questions I have:

1. What exactly are the penalties, if any, for not declaring my income in the past 6 years?
2. How do I file for all the years that I didn't?
3. Can I do this myself or should I get a professional to help out?

Comment: "have lived outside the U.S. all my life" - How are you a citizen if you never lived in the US?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Perhaps OP was [born to US citizen parents abroad](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/abroad/events-and-records/birth.html).

Comment: @dg99 - I am completely out of my element. You can be born overseas, never set foot here, but have tax obligations to US? Just learned something new today.

Comment: Yes. :(  The only way to not even potentially owe tax to the United States during year X is to BOTH (a) not be a citizen during year X AND (b) not earn any income within the United States during year X.

Answer (score 8):

Do NOT talk to the IRS on your own. Get a EA/CPA licensed in the US and operating in your home country to help you catch up. US embassies have lists of some of those, check the embassy in your country.

The penalties for US citizens living abroad are DRACONIAN. Where a US resident would get a slap on the wrist - you may be driven bankrupt and thrown into jail (if you ever set foot in the US). You can get a $100000 penalty each year for each bank account you own (even though you may not be liable for any taxes at all) just for not reporting it to the US government.

Being a US citizen and not living in the US is essentially a punishable offense through the tax laws. be aware of it and prepare to handle it as such.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to say that I disagree with both of the previous answers to this question. 
I came up against a lot of similar "*advice*" when I was dealing with this issue personally. I know this is an old-ish question but hopefully this will help future searchers.

1. (Added) The foreign income exclusion is currently $90k per annum. If your income is lower than this you will owe **no** tax and this is a paperwork exercise.
2. The statute of limitations for tax issues is 3 years. Therefore you **will not** need to file returns for more than the last 3 years.
3. The IRS has a **special program** in place called Streamlined Filing to help non-resident, non-Filer U.S. Taxpayers become compliant. If your finances are fairly simple and your income is *normal* you should be able to complete this process yourself. http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Streamlined-Filing-Compliance-Procedures
4. Although the *potential* penalties are draconian they are based on the *willful misrepresentation* and the amount of tax owed. Most filers in this circumstance have **no** tax owing so no penalties applicable in that case. Also, I suspect the cost of handling most foreign filings exceeds the revenue they bring in and the IRS is disinclined to delve deeply for those with modest incomes.
5. "Specialist" US tax advisors for foreign resident US citizens are rare and therefore **very** expensive. Worse, their interests also conflict with yours, .i.e., the more years and forms they file for you the more they earn. Carefully consider your *other* options before spending thousands of dollars on one of them.

My final piece of advice would be to refer primarily to IRS website for information and treat everything else you read as suspicious.

I haven't provided a lot of links to the IRS site because the IRS (in their wisdom) seem to change them fairly often. Many of mine have already aged out from last year. Google will take you where you need to go.

Comment: "The statute of limitations for tax issues is 3 years. Therefore you will not need to file returns for more than the last 3 years." This is wrong. The statute of limitations means the IRS has 3 years after you file your return to audit your taxes. If you never file your return, the statute of limitations never even starts.

Comment: That may be true in theory, however Streamlined processing **specifies** filing 3 years returns, c.f. my last sentence about using IRS provided info as your primary source of information.

Comment: "Taxpayers who are concerned that their failure to report income, pay tax, and submit required information returns was due to willful conduct and who therefore seek assurance that they will not be subject to criminal liability and/or substantial monetary penalties should consider participating the Offshore Voluntary Disclosure Program and should consult with their professional or legal advisers." It seems the process you suggest is not a slam dunk, and member @litteadv suggestion to seek a professional is echoed by the IRS.

Comment: So is your answer essentially to use the program you mention in bullet point 2?  What "other options" are you referring to in point 4?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Note the reference to "willful conduct", most foreign resident non-filers are not aware of the filing requirement. Largely because the US is the **only** western country that requires it.

Comment: @dg99 The Streamlined program is just a simplification. Filers are free to simply submit them as normal. I would strongly encourage them to attempt to complete the forms to assess how much risk they really have. The foreign income exclusion is quite high at $90k (ignoring double taxation for the moment!) and most filers will be under the limit and have $0 to pay.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvoted. It's very insightful and based on JH's personal experience. This is the best answer to the OP's question, thanks for coming back to an old question.

Comment: While this answer is basically correct it doesn't change the fact that he needs to lawyer up.  This isn't a place to navigate alone!

Comment: -1. NEVER EVER "become compliant" on your own without a professional advice. Ever. Statute of limitations doesn't start until the return is filed. Not filing *is* a willful neglect. "treat everything else you read as suspicious" - yes, especially this answer.

Comment: @Rocky this is being downvoted because it is **wrong**.

Comment: @littleadv Professional advice on these cases (if you can even find it) is _easily_ 5-10% of the median gross income in Western European countries (I know first hand) and anyone earning at that level would **owe nothing** and face no penalties. The IRS has clearly recognised that many people are simply not aware of the filing requirement and wish to become compliant. Unless you can cite specific instances where foreign resident citizens with modest incomes were penalised by the IRS (which don't exist, I looked) then your comments are less than helpful.

Comment: @JoeHarris here's an example of an elderly lady who "wasn't aware of the filing requirement": http://maplesandbox.ca/2013/is-this-fair-3200-fbar-penalty/ The point is: if you're not aware of the filing requirements - you're probably also not aware of the PFIC, CFC, Foreign Trust, FBAR and other rules. All of which have huge penalties **for not filing**.

Comment: @littleadv Very interesting, someone with an undeclared **$42 million dollars** should definitely "lawyer up". However it doesn't really serve as an object lesson for the rest of us with more meagre savings and income far under the caps.

Comment: @JoeHarris penalties for not filing are $10K per account per year *if no taxes owed*. I'd lawyer up too. I guess you're lucky in casinos. I thought your point was that if someone "doesn't know he was supposed to declare" he's golden. I've shown you that that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Where you live doesn't matter to IRS. So the same penalties apply.

2, 3. Get professional help in filing the taxes for the past few years to get you up to speed to current

[Here are the details](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/U.S.-Citizens-and-Resident-Aliens-Abroad) from the IRS website

[Also here is](http://www.irs.gov/uac/IRS-Offers-New-Toll-Free-Numbers-to-Assist-Taxpayers) IRS phone number aimed at assisting taxpayers

```
800-829-1040
```